# Check if the date is in date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord, range

I have an array of objects created like this:

```
all_project_assignments = ProjectAssignment.where(active: true, hour_type_id: 1)
```

Now I want to use this result array to select only assignments within date range. Date range is:

```
date_range = @current_month.at_beginning_of_month..@current_month.at_end_of_month
```

And each member of all_project_assignments has field entry_date that has to be within range.

My alternative is:

```
project_assignments = ProjectAssignment.where(active: true, hour_type_id: 1, entry_date: date_range)
```

But I don't want another db query. So, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Am I correct that you want to preserve the original result set, and basically filter the array to create a second?

Comment: yes... if it is possible since that is the same model, just different date range

Comment: Check out the bottom of Manuel's answer, that should solve your problem I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain Queries together:

```
all_project_assignments = ProjectAssignment.where(active: true, hour_type_id: 1)
date_range = @current_month.at_beginning_of_month..@current_month.at_end_of_month
project_assignments = all_project_assignments.where(entry_date: date_range)
```

However, this will query the DB again.

If you want to filter your retrieved Rows, simply do

```
project_assignments = all_project_assignments.select do |assignment|
    assignment.entry_date.between?(@current_month.at_beginning_of_month, @current_month.at_end_of_month)
end
```

Comment: That would result in a second db query though.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the question first. Added a second option that does not query the DB again.

Comment: Yep, that should do it. They'll also probably need to invoke [compact](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-compact) since the resulting array may contain nils for anything not between those days.

Comment: Yes, this will do now. Thanks everybody.

Comment: @Marija click the little green checkmark on this answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) on Range conditions:

```
Client.where(created_at: (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight)
```

That will produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.created_at BETWEEN '2008-12-21 00:00:00' AND '2008-12-22 00:00:00')
```

So in you case:

```
all_project_assignments = ProjectAssignment.where(active: true, hour_type_id: 1, entry_date: @current_month.at_beginning_of_month..@current_month.at_end_of_month)
```

Beware if you compare by the current month `(1..12)` you will get results from the same month, but from last years.

Answer (score 0):

If range is nothing but entire month then can you try with this query?

```
project_assignments = all_project_assignments.select do |assignment|
    assignment.entry_date.month == @current_month
end
```

possible if @current_month is integer